# Navicat store mysql query result into variable

Tags: mysql, variables, navicat

I'm using Navicat to manage a MySql database and I want to store a query result into a variable. I tried these two options and none of them is working, but they do work if used directly from MySql console.

First syntax:

```
SET @var =(SELECT id FROM client where `name` = "gerrard");
SELECT @var;
```

Second syntax:

```
SELECT id INTO @var FROM client where `name` = "gerrard";
SELECT @var;
```

Both of them shows null in the output.

Comment: what's the datatype of `id` in `client` table?

Comment: @TseKitYam the datatype is int

Comment: ```CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `orange` (`id` int NOT NULL, `name` varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ); INSERT INTO `orange` ( `id`, `name`) VALUES ( '0', 'gerrard'); SET @var =(SELECT id FROM `orange` WHERE `name` = "gerrard"); SELECT @var;``` Please try running these queries, see if the problem is related to your table or not. FYI, Navciat 11.2.14 on mac shows correct value, `0`.